# xhpro error in make step occured

Tags: php, makefile, xhprof

This is my first question on Stack Overflow.

I don't know a lot about *make*.

According to [this guide](http://michaelsanford.com/compiling-xhprof-for-php-5-4/), an error occurred with make:

```
    /bin/bash /home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/include -I/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/main -I/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension -I/usr/include/php/20151012 -I/usr/include/php/20151012/main -I/usr/include/php/20151012/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c -o xhprof.lo 
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/include -I/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/main -I/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension -I/usr/include/php/20151012 -I/usr/include/php/20151012/main -I/usr/include/php/20151012/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/xhprof.o
In file included from /usr/include/php/20151012/main/php.h:34:0,
                 from /home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:27:
/usr/include/php/20151012/main/php_config.h:2458:0: warning: "_GNU_SOURCE" redefined
 #define _GNU_SOURCE 1
 ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:24:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 # define _GNU_SOURCE
 ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:236:1: warning: ‘visibility’ attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
 static ZEND_DLEXPORT void (*_zend_execute) (zend_op_array *ops TSRMLS_DC);
 ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:240:28: warning: ‘visibility’ attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
                            int ret TSRMLS_DC);
                            ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c: In function ‘hp_init_profiler_state’:
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:625:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘FREE_ZVAL’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     FREE_ZVAL(hp_globals.stats_count);
     ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:627:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘MAKE_STD_ZVAL’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   MAKE_STD_ZVAL(hp_globals.stats_count);
   ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:635:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘restore_cpu_affinity’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     restore_cpu_affinity(&hp_globals.prev_mask);
     ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:639:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘bind_to_cpu’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   bind_to_cpu((int) (rand() % hp_globals.cpu_num));
   ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c: In function ‘hp_get_function_name’:
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:895:21: error: ‘zend_execute_data {aka struct _zend_execute_data}’ has no member named ‘function_state’
     curr_func = data->function_state.function;
                     ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:898:10: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     func = curr_func->common.function_name;
          ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:909:13: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
         cls = curr_func->common.scope->name;
             ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:910:22: error: ‘zend_execute_data {aka struct _zend_execute_data}’ has no member named ‘object’
       } else if (data->object) {
                      ^
In file included from /usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend.h:31:0,
                 from /usr/include/php/20151012/main/php.h:36,
                 from /home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:27:
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:911:28: error: ‘zend_execute_data {aka struct _zend_execute_data}’ has no member named ‘object’
         cls = Z_OBJCE(*data->object)->name;
                            ^
/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend_types.h:530:26: note: in definition of macro ‘Z_OBJ’
 #define Z_OBJ(zval)     (zval).value.obj
                          ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:911:15: note: in expansion of macro ‘Z_OBJCE’
         cls = Z_OBJCE(*data->object)->name;
               ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:930:34: error: ‘znode_op {aka const union _znode_op}’ has no member named ‘u’
       curr_op = data->opline->op2.u.constant.value.lval;
                                  ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:963:41: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘hp_get_base_filename’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
         filename = hp_get_base_filename((curr_func->op_array).filename);
                                         ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:856:14: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘zend_string * {aka struct _zend_string *}’
 static char *hp_get_base_filename(char *filename) {
              ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c: In function ‘hp_inc_count’:
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1043:26: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘zend_hash_find’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   if (zend_hash_find(ht, name, strlen(name) + 1, &data) == SUCCESS) {
                          ^
In file included from /usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend.h:36:0,
                 from /usr/include/php/20151012/main/php.h:36,
                 from /home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:27:
/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend_hash.h:154:30: note: expected ‘zend_string * {aka struct _zend_string *}’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
 ZEND_API zval* ZEND_FASTCALL zend_hash_find(const HashTable *ht, zend_string *key);
                              ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1043:7: error: too many arguments to function ‘zend_hash_find’
   if (zend_hash_find(ht, name, strlen(name) + 1, &data) == SUCCESS) {
       ^
In file included from /usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend.h:36:0,
                 from /usr/include/php/20151012/main/php.h:36,
                 from /home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:27:
/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend_hash.h:154:30: note: declared here
 ZEND_API zval* ZEND_FASTCALL zend_hash_find(const HashTable *ht, zend_string *key);
                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend.h:31:0,
                 from /usr/include/php/20151012/main/php.h:36,
                 from /home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:27:
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1044:30: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘Z_LVAL_PP’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     ZVAL_LONG(*(zval**)data, Z_LVAL_PP((zval**)data) + count);
                              ^
/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend_types.h:610:19: note: in definition of macro ‘ZVAL_LONG’
   Z_LVAL_P(__z) = l;    \
                   ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c: In function ‘hp_hash_lookup’:
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1067:26: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘zend_hash_find’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   if (zend_hash_find(ht, symbol, strlen(symbol) + 1, &data) == SUCCESS) {
                          ^
In file included from /usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend.h:36:0,
                 from /usr/include/php/20151012/main/php.h:36,
                 from /home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:27:
/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend_hash.h:154:30: note: expected ‘zend_string * {aka struct _zend_string *}’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
 ZEND_API zval* ZEND_FASTCALL zend_hash_find(const HashTable *ht, zend_string *key);
                              ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1067:7: error: too many arguments to function ‘zend_hash_find’
   if (zend_hash_find(ht, symbol, strlen(symbol) + 1, &data) == SUCCESS) {
       ^
In file included from /usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend.h:36:0,
                 from /usr/include/php/20151012/main/php.h:36,
                 from /home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:27:
/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend_hash.h:154:30: note: declared here
 ZEND_API zval* ZEND_FASTCALL zend_hash_find(const HashTable *ht, zend_string *key);
                              ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c: In function ‘hp_sample_stack’:
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1131:21: error: macro "add_assoc_string" passed 4 arguments, but takes just 3
                    1);
                     ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1128:3: error: ‘add_assoc_string’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   add_assoc_string(hp_globals.stats_count,
   ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1128:3: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c: In function ‘hp_execute_internal’:
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1639:43: error: ‘zend_execute_data {aka struct _zend_execute_data}’ has no member named ‘op_array’
   func = hp_get_function_name(current_data->op_array TSRMLS_CC);
                                           ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1623:21: warning: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
 #define EX(element) ((execute_data)->element)
                     ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1647:23: note: in expansion of macro ‘EX’
     zend_op *opline = EX(opline);
                       ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1623:36: error: ‘zend_execute_data {aka struct _zend_execute_data}’ has no member named ‘function_state’
 #define EX(element) ((execute_data)->element)
                                    ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1648:33: note: in expansion of macro ‘EX’
     ((zend_internal_function *) EX(function_state).function)->handler(
                                 ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1624:25: error: ‘temp_variable’ undeclared (first use in this function)
 #define EX_T(offset) (*(temp_variable *)((char *) EX(Ts) + offset))
                         ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1650:24: note: in expansion of macro ‘EX_T’
                        EX_T(opline->result.u.var).var.ptr,
                        ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1624:40: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
 #define EX_T(offset) (*(temp_variable *)((char *) EX(Ts) + offset))
                                        ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1650:24: note: in expansion of macro ‘EX_T’
                        EX_T(opline->result.u.var).var.ptr,
                        ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1623:36: error: ‘zend_execute_data {aka struct _zend_execute_data}’ has no member named ‘Ts’
 #define EX(element) ((execute_data)->element)
                                    ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1624:51: note: in expansion of macro ‘EX’
 #define EX_T(offset) (*(temp_variable *)((char *) EX(Ts) + offset))
                                                   ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1650:24: note: in expansion of macro ‘EX_T’
                        EX_T(opline->result.u.var).var.ptr,
                        ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1623:36: error: ‘zend_execute_data {aka struct _zend_execute_data}’ has no member named ‘function_state’
 #define EX(element) ((execute_data)->element)
                                    ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1651:24: note: in expansion of macro ‘EX’
                        EX(function_state).function->common.return_reference ?
                        ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1624:40: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
 #define EX_T(offset) (*(temp_variable *)((char *) EX(Ts) + offset))
                                        ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1652:25: note: in expansion of macro ‘EX_T’
                        &EX_T(opline->result.u.var).var.ptr:NULL,
                         ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1623:36: error: ‘zend_execute_data {aka struct _zend_execute_data}’ has no member named ‘Ts’
 #define EX(element) ((execute_data)->element)
                                    ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1624:51: note: in expansion of macro ‘EX’
 #define EX_T(offset) (*(temp_variable *)((char *) EX(Ts) + offset))
                                                   ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1652:25: note: in expansion of macro ‘EX_T’
                        &EX_T(opline->result.u.var).var.ptr:NULL,
                         ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1623:36: error: ‘zend_execute_data {aka struct _zend_execute_data}’ has no member named ‘object’
 #define EX(element) ((execute_data)->element)
                                    ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1653:24: note: in expansion of macro ‘EX’
                        EX(object), ret TSRMLS_CC);
                        ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c: In function ‘hp_compile_file’:
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1683:35: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘hp_get_base_filename’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
   filename = hp_get_base_filename(file_handle->filename);
                                   ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:856:14: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
 static char *hp_get_base_filename(char *filename) {
              ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c: In function ‘hp_begin’:
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1722:19: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     _zend_execute = zend_execute;
                   ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1723:19: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
     zend_execute  = hp_execute;
                   ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1726:28: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     _zend_execute_internal = zend_execute_internal;
                            ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1731:29: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
       zend_execute_internal = hp_execute_internal;
                             ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c: In function ‘hp_stop’:
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1796:25: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
   zend_execute          = _zend_execute;
                         ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1797:25: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   zend_execute_internal = _zend_execute_internal;
                         ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c: In function ‘hp_zval_at_key’:
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1823:13: error: ‘zval {aka struct _zval_struct}’ has no member named ‘type’
   if (values->type == IS_ARRAY) {
             ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1829:28: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘zend_hash_find’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     if (zend_hash_find(ht, key, len, (void**)&value) == SUCCESS) {
                            ^
In file included from /usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend.h:36:0,
                 from /usr/include/php/20151012/main/php.h:36,
                 from /home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:27:
/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend_hash.h:154:30: note: expected ‘zend_string * {aka struct _zend_string *}’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
 ZEND_API zval* ZEND_FASTCALL zend_hash_find(const HashTable *ht, zend_string *key);
                              ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1829:9: error: too many arguments to function ‘zend_hash_find’
     if (zend_hash_find(ht, key, len, (void**)&value) == SUCCESS) {
         ^
In file included from /usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend.h:36:0,
                 from /usr/include/php/20151012/main/php.h:36,
                 from /home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:27:
/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend_hash.h:154:30: note: declared here
 ZEND_API zval* ZEND_FASTCALL zend_hash_find(const HashTable *ht, zend_string *key);
                              ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c: In function ‘hp_strings_in_zval’:
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1853:13: error: ‘zval {aka struct _zval_struct}’ has no member named ‘type’
   if (values->type == IS_ARRAY) {
             ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1873:47: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘zend_hash_get_current_key_ex’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
       type = zend_hash_get_current_key_ex(ht, &str, &len, &idx, 0, NULL);
                                               ^
In file included from /usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend.h:36:0,
                 from /usr/include/php/20151012/main/php.h:36,
                 from /home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:27:
/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend_hash.h:168:30: note: expected ‘zend_string ** {aka struct _zend_string **}’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
 ZEND_API int   ZEND_FASTCALL zend_hash_get_current_key_ex(const HashTable *ht, zend_string **str_index, zend_ulong *num_index, HashPosi
                              ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1873:53: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘zend_hash_get_current_key_ex’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
       type = zend_hash_get_current_key_ex(ht, &str, &len, &idx, 0, NULL);
                                                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend.h:36:0,
                 from /usr/include/php/20151012/main/php.h:36,
                 from /home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:27:
/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend_hash.h:168:30: note: expected ‘zend_ulong * {aka long unsigned int *}’ but argument is of type ‘uint * {aka unsigned int *}’
 ZEND_API int   ZEND_FASTCALL zend_hash_get_current_key_ex(const HashTable *ht, zend_string **str_index, zend_ulong *num_index, HashPosi
                              ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1873:59: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘zend_hash_get_current_key_ex’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
       type = zend_hash_get_current_key_ex(ht, &str, &len, &idx, 0, NULL);
                                                           ^
In file included from /usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend.h:36:0,
                 from /usr/include/php/20151012/main/php.h:36,
                 from /home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:27:
/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend_hash.h:168:30: note: expected ‘HashPosition * {aka unsigned int *}’ but argument is of type ‘ulong * {aka long unsigned int *}’
 ZEND_API int   ZEND_FASTCALL zend_hash_get_current_key_ex(const HashTable *ht, zend_string **str_index, zend_ulong *num_index, HashPosi
                              ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1873:14: error: too many arguments to function ‘zend_hash_get_current_key_ex’
       type = zend_hash_get_current_key_ex(ht, &str, &len, &idx, 0, NULL);
              ^
In file included from /usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend.h:36:0,
                 from /usr/include/php/20151012/main/php.h:36,
                 from /home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:27:
/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend_hash.h:168:30: note: declared here
 ZEND_API int   ZEND_FASTCALL zend_hash_get_current_key_ex(const HashTable *ht, zend_string **str_index, zend_ulong *num_index, HashPosi
                              ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1876:58: error: macro "zend_hash_get_current_data" passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1
         if ((zend_hash_get_current_data(ht, (void**)&data) == SUCCESS) &&
                                                          ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1876:14: error: ‘zend_hash_get_current_data’ undeclared (first use in this function)
         if ((zend_hash_get_current_data(ht, (void**)&data) == SUCCESS) &&
              ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1877:13: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘Z_TYPE_PP’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
             Z_TYPE_PP(data) == IS_STRING &&
             ^
In file included from /usr/include/string.h:630:0,
                 from /usr/include/php/20151012/main/php_config.h:2517,
                 from /usr/include/php/20151012/main/php.h:34,
                 from /home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:27:
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1878:20: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘Z_STRVAL_PP’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
             strcmp(Z_STRVAL_PP(data), ROOT_SYMBOL)) { /* do not ignore "main" */
                    ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1878:20: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘__builtin_strlen’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
             strcmp(Z_STRVAL_PP(data), ROOT_SYMBOL)) { /* do not ignore "main" */
                    ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1878:20: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1878:20: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘__builtin_strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
             strcmp(Z_STRVAL_PP(data), ROOT_SYMBOL)) { /* do not ignore "main" */
                    ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1878:20: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1878:20: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘__builtin_strlen’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
             strcmp(Z_STRVAL_PP(data), ROOT_SYMBOL)) { /* do not ignore "main" */
                    ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1878:20: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1878:20: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘__builtin_strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
             strcmp(Z_STRVAL_PP(data), ROOT_SYMBOL)) { /* do not ignore "main" */
                    ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1878:20: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1878:20: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘__builtin_strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
             strcmp(Z_STRVAL_PP(data), ROOT_SYMBOL)) { /* do not ignore "main" */
                    ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1878:20: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1878:20: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘__builtin_strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
             strcmp(Z_STRVAL_PP(data), ROOT_SYMBOL)) { /* do not ignore "main" */
                    ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1878:20: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
In file included from /usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend.h:33:0,
                 from /usr/include/php/20151012/main/php.h:36,
                 from /home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:27:
/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend_alloc.h:172:35: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘_estrdup’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
 #define estrdup(s)       _estrdup((s) ZEND_FILE_LINE_CC ZEND_FILE_LINE_EMPTY_CC)
                                   ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1879:24: note: in expansion of macro ‘estrdup’
           result[ix] = estrdup(Z_STRVAL_PP(data));
                        ^
In file included from /usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend.h:33:0,
                 from /usr/include/php/20151012/main/php.h:36,
                 from /home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:27:
/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend_alloc.h:84:31: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 ZEND_API char*  ZEND_FASTCALL _estrdup(const char *s ZEND_FILE_LINE_DC ZEND_FILE_LINE_ORIG_DC) ZEND_ATTRIBUTE_MALLOC;
                               ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:1884:19: error: ‘zval {aka struct _zval_struct}’ has no member named ‘type’
   } else if(values->type == IS_STRING) {
                   ^
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c: At top level:
/home/hamid/xhprof-0.9.2/extension/xhprof.c:789:10: warning: ‘hp_globals’ is static but used in inline function ‘hp_ignore_entry’ which is not static
   return hp_globals.ignored_function_names != NULL && 
          ^
Makefile:193: recipe for target 'xhprof.lo' failed
make: *** [xhprof.lo] Error 1
```

I don't know about the **C** language. Maybe some bad configuration for make caused this error. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to install xhprof and getting error then you need to just follow the below steps (I assume you have a working ubuntu system with preinstalled dependencies):

1. git clone https://github.com/longxinH/xhprof
2. cd xhprof/extension
3. phpize
4. ./configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config7.0
5. sudo make && sudo make install

You can get reference [here](https://github.com/longxinH/xhprof)

Thanks